# resize iframe when click an element to show all links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

guys
i have navbar include in iframe and and want this navbar to be mobile friendly 
so when click icons link to show all links want the iframe resize to be able see all of them

could yo please help me in this

```
 <iframe class ="navbar" src="http://mrholidayer.com/navbar2.php"  scrolling="yes"  frameborder="0" style="width:100%;" onload="this.style.height=this.contentDocument.body.scrollHeight +'px';"></iframe>
```

i want this iframe reize when click an element not while page loading only

Comment: All questions on SO should be asking for help on something people have already attempted and failed it, which usually incorporates showing your previous work in your question. SO isn't a code-writing service. That being said, iframes aren't the most state-of-the-art technology to choose from in the first place when you want mobile-friendly... Why don't you use PHP to include the script instead (`<?php include('/navbar2.php'); ?>`), then resize whatever container it's in?

Comment: try adding a resize ahndler on your iframes window (this.contentDocument) to adjust the size

Comment: i tried to include it but the problem in the css so please could you tell me more how can i solve this problem